# Dictionary foreach loop with multiple occurences

Tags: c#, performance, hash-map

A little look on what are Dictionaries:

```
dictWordCounter<string, int> 
dictWordPercent<string, double>
topTwentySeven<string, double>
```

- `WordCounter` is the number of words. For example, if the word frog is 10 times it will be {frog, 10}.
- `WordPercent` is the percent after some math in the program. For example, frog could be {frog, 0,55}.
- `topTwentySeven` is the top 27 values from the `WordPercent` dictionary that I want to operate on.

So, I need to count something like this:

- If a word is just one, count it normally
- If a word is twice or more, count it x2
- Total number of words (after x2) must be still 27, not more

For example if it was "topThree" and words:

{Frog, 2}, {Monkey, 1}, {Giraffee, 1}, and their values from Percent Dictionary would be {Frog, 0,1}, {Giraffee, 0,2}, {Monkey, 0,45}, I want to count: 0,1*0,1*0,2 and (1-0,1) * (1-0,1)*(1-0,2).

Could someone look on this and check if it can be improved?

```
   var topTwentySeven = dictWordPercent.OrderByDescending(kvp => Math.Abs(kvp.Value - 0.5))
        .Take(27)
        .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);

    int compare = 0;
    double temp2 = 1.0, A = 1.0, B = 1.0;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 27; )
    {               

        foreach (var word in topTwentySeven)
        {
        dictWordCounter.TryGetValue(word.Key, out compare);
            if (compare >= 2 && counter < 26)
            {
                temp = word.Value;
                temp2 = temp * temp;
                A *= temp2;
                B *= (1 - temp2);
                counter = counter + 2;

            }
            else if (compare == 1 && counter < 27)
            {
                temp = word.Value;
                A *= temp;
                B *= (1 - temp);
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
            else if (counter >= 27)
            {
                //Do nothing
            }
        }
    }

int top27C = topTwentySeven.Count();

double aN = 0.0, bN = 0.0;
aN = Math.Pow(A, (1 / top27C));
bN = Math.Pow(B, (1 / top27C));
```

I need both A and B.

```
totalSum = Math.Round(((aN / (aN + bN)) * 100), 2);
```

Comment: I knew there was a reason to use . as decimal point

Comment: Where's the method signature? Can you include that please?

Comment: Which method? The one converting WordCounter to WordPercentage?

Comment: i'm confused. you say count twice but then square the value? You should be able to reduce this down to a single line of linq. But I dont understand the requirement

Comment: @Ewan twice in the meaning of square, I am multiplying ( * ) all the values from dictionary. So if all the values would be single in WordCount I would multiple all of them, but if one of the values would be 2,3,4..n times in the wordCount dictionary I would multiply by this value twice, but keep in mind to count only 27 total values.

Comment: what about B do you need to return this as well? you should provide the whole function as rubberduck asked

Comment: @Ewan yeah, Sure, I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated. You have some tricky bits to do in linq, but you can see the code is much clearer (although less efficient) without the loop. You could further neaten, by creating a class WordCountAndValue with methods rather than using the anon type and inline ifs

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace UnitTestProject3
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> wordCounts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            wordCounts.Add("t1", 1);
            wordCounts.Add("t2", 2);
            wordCounts.Add("t3", 3);
            wordCounts.Add("t4", 4);
            wordCounts.Add("t5", 5);

            Dictionary<string, double> wordPercent = new Dictionary<string, double>();
            wordPercent.Add("t1", 0.3);
            wordPercent.Add("t2", 0.4);
            wordPercent.Add("t3", 0.5);
            wordPercent.Add("t4", 0.6);
            wordPercent.Add("t5", 0.7);

            var wordsCombined = wordPercent
                .Select(kvp => new { word = kvp.Key, percent = kvp.Value, count = GetCount(wordCounts, kvp.Key) })
                .OrderByDescending(i => i.percent);

            //find number to get
            int target = 5;
            int count = 0;
            var sample = wordsCombined.TakeWhile(i=> target > (count += (i.count >= 2 ? 2 : i.count))).ToList();

            Assert.AreEqual(2, sample.Count());

            //find A
            double A = sample
                .Select(i => i.count >= 2 ? i.percent * i.percent : i.percent)
                .Aggregate(1.0, (t, n) => t * n);

            //find B
            double B = sample
                .Select(i => i.count >= 2 ? i.percent * i.percent : i.percent)
                .Aggregate(1.0, (t, n) => t * (1-n));

            Assert.AreEqual(2, sample.Count());
            Assert.AreEqual((double)0.1764, Math.Round(A,4), "A is incorrect");
            Assert.AreEqual((double)0.3264, Math.Round(B, 4), "B is incorrect");

        }

        public int GetCount(Dictionary<string, int> counts, string key)
        {
            if (!counts.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            return counts[key];
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't write dead code - it rots like a corpse and makes it hard to maintain your code:

> ```
> else if (counter >= 27)
> {
>     //Do nothing
> }
> ```

Just delete this.

---

You can use the `++` increment operator here:

> ```
> counter = counter + 1;
> ```

Like this:

```
++counter;
```

---

There is a `+=` operator you can use here:

> ```
> counter = counter + 2;
> ```

Like this:

```
counter += 2;
```

---

There is a `Math.Pow()` method you can use:

> ```
> temp2 = temp * temp;
> ```

Like this:

```
temp2 = Math.Pow(temp, 2);
```

Comment: I would have written counter++. It's a little easier to read and you don't care if it's incremented before or after the value is accessed.